# Repairing exterior cement wall

Tags: repair, concrete, walls, exterior, stucco

I have an exterior wall on one side of a brick building that appears to be stucco or cement. Some of it is starting to come off in sheets. Basically, there is one layer, maybe the thickness of orange peel that can easily be snapped off at the edge. Behind it is something that is somewhere between the texture of sand and sandstone that crumbles readily when touched.

I am wondering:

- is repairing the wall a straightforward DIY project
- should I be worried about this "sand" behind the outer layer of cement/stucco
- do I need to scrape away this entire layer then put on a new layer, or can I just repair sections of the wall?
- I assume I'm going to want to use some combination of concrete/cement and sand for the wall. Is there a recommended mixture to use for this?
- The wall to be repaired is very high -- it extends the entire height of the house which is 3 stories; are there safe ways to do this higher up? Would I need to set up scaffolding or could I work from a ladder?

I'm guessing pictures would be helpful but right now I'm in the early stages of determining whether this is even a DIY project. If it really isn't possible to answer without pictures I'll try to take some; please let me know what specific pictures to take.